# What are the potential columns I can receive in a Nominatim API Reverse Geocode lookup?

Tags: openstreetmap, nominatim

As per this link : [here](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim#Examples)

It's clear with `&addressdetails=1` the response can be broken down into Elements.

Problem is, I've looked at a series of responses for different osm_id's and the element list can include very different, additional elements, which are not present in this example. (e.g  or )

Is there a list I can get which documents all the possible Elements that can be sent back? I cannot find this documentation anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The responses are defined by the tags found in openstreetmap.

Since OSM allows arbitrary tagging it isn't possible to define all the possible tags but you can find a list of the specifically supported ones here:

https://github.com/twain47/Nominatim/blob/master/lib/lib.php#L334

Answer (score 2):

There is currently no documentation about the possible elements, except for the [source code](https://github.com/twain47/Nominatim).